# "Прилипающие" заголовки ленты Instargam

Tags: java, android, instagram

Если прокручивать ленту инстаграма заголовки каждого item в списке будут как бы "прилипать" на место toolbar. Если Вы пользовались instagram, то поймете как это выглядит. Интересно как реализовать подобный функционал для списка? Может есть какие то библиотеки имеющие подобный функционал?

Comment: stickyjs например. вообще по запросу sticky div можно много разных велосипедов для этого найти

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть библиотеки, реализующие данный функционал:

**Один** https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

**Два** https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders

**Три** https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders